# Where can I find my bundle identifier, and why is it important?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush, mobilepush-ios

I keep seeing references to bundle identifier in the documentation and notes, but I don't understand why it's so important. Can I change it if I want to later? Do I need a different bundle identifier for my dev app and prod app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bundle identifier is the unique identification of an app within Apple's universe. It must be globally unique, and any individual application only has one bundle identifier. When Push is provisioned with Apple, the bundle identifier supplied is used to create a topic for sending. This is later combined with a device token to create a unique representation for every device in Apple's system. While an iOS app has multiple provisioning profiles and APNS certificates, it will only ever have one bundle identifer.

The bundle identifier can be found in the applications Info.plist form, or under the General tab of your target's build setting.